# confusion in MIPS storing bits,

Tags: binary, mips, machine-code

hi im trying to store a bit into a temp. register. Am i doing this correctly? and while i am at it, i am trying to see how many 1's are in the binary forms of a decimal number (0-16) am i doing this right? here is the chunk of code that matters, the rest works fine(just output and what not)

```
# for (i = 0; i <= 16; i++)
li $s0, 0 # i = 0

li $s3, 0 #constant zero

li $s4, 0 #i-2=0

bgt $s0, 16, bottom
top:
# calculate n from i
# Your part starts here

sb $t1, ($s0) #store LSB from number i in t1

sltu $t7,$s3,$t1 # check if t1 is a 1, if it is set t7 = 1

add $s1 ,$s3,$t1 # add 1 to n

ble $s4, 7, bloop # loop through rest of bits

bloop:

srl $t7, $s0, 1  # move bits in i right one, bringing in a zero from the left

sltu $t6, $s3, $t7 # check if t7 is a 1, if it is set t6 to 1

add $s1, $t6, $s1  # add increment n up 1

bgt $s4, 7, continue # break out of loop

continue:
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that for sb $t1, ($s0), it is giving me an error---Runtime exception at 0x00400034: address out of range 0x00000000

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at your code:

```
    li $s0, 0
    li $s3, 0
    li $s4, 0
```

these instructions set the 3 registers `$s0`, `$s3`, and `$s4` to 0

```
    bgt $s0, 16, bottom
```

Branch to `bottom` if `$s0` is greater than 16.  Now `$s0` will be 0 initially, and you have not labels *before* this, so there's no way to get back here, so this branch will never be taken.  Also, it won't even assemble, as you never define the `bottom` label anywhere.

```
top:
```

The label `top`, so you can branch back to here as a loop -- but your code has no branches to `top`, so it never actually will.

```
    sb $t1, ($s0)
```

store a byte from `$t1` at the address given by `$s0`.  Now the first time into the loop, `$t0` has never been set to anything, so what are you storing?  Worse, `$s0` has been set to 0, so you're storing at address 0, which will crash (give a runtime error).

So this store really makes no sense.  It's storing garbage to an invalid address.

```
    sltu $t7,$s3,$t1
```

This compares `$s3` to `$t1` and sets `$t7` to 0 or 1 depending on whether `$s3` is less than `$t1`.  `$t1` is still garbage (you've never put anything into it), but it turns out that doesn't matter as `$s3` is 0, so the comparison will always be false.  Not that it matters anyways, as you never *use* `$t7` for anything after this.

```
    add $s1 ,$s3,$t1
```

Add `$s3` (which is 0) to `$t1` (which is garbage), and store the result(garbage) in `$s1`

```
    ble $s4, 7, bloop
bloop:
```

Compare `$s4` to `7` and branch if it is less than 7.  Since `$s4` is 0, it will branch, but since `bloop` is immediately after this, the branch has no effect.  So this (and the label) might was well be deleted, as they don't do anything.

```
    srl $t7, $s0, 1
```

shift `$s0` left 1 bit position and store it into `$t7`.  `$s0` was set to 0 above, and shifting 0 gives 0, so this stores 0 in `$t7`.

```
    sltu $t6, $s3, $t7
```

compare `$s3`(0) to `$t7`(0) and store the less-than result in `$t6` (0)

```
    add $s1, $t6, $s1
```

add `$t6` to `$s1`, putting the result in `$s1` -- this is the first instruction since the first three `li` instructions that makes any kind of sense.  But as `$t6` was zer0, it doesn't actually do anything

```
    bgt $s4, 7, continue
continue:
```

Another branch that does nothing as the target is right after the branch.

So overally, you code looks like a bunch of randomly chosen instructions that don't do anything sensible.  There's no loop, despite comments about looping.  There nothing related to "bits" at all, despite title of the question.

Comment: ya i see now that i messed up setting some values. the loops bottom and top work, they exist outside this bit of code i took out of the larger program. continue (to my understanding) is just breaking me out of the bloop loop and putting me back in the orignal lopp i am in. which is top.

Comment: this is my end goal for this block of code:   Find the number of 1's in the binary representaions of the numbers 0-16 and store them in register $s1.